# Google Drive API File List Issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive API (v3), to List/Download/Upload files. The API is being used in a mobile React Native App.

Everything was working fine last month and suddenly it stopped working because the File List API response changed for some reason.

**Dependencies used:**

```
react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper": "^1.1.2"
react-native-google-signin": "^1.2.2"
```

**Current File List Response**

```
{ type: 'default',
  status: 200,
  ok: true,
  statusText: undefined,
  headers: 
   { map: 
      { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        server: 'GSE',
        expires: 'Sat, 27 Jul 2019 18:38:32 GMT',
        'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"',
        date: 'Sat, 27 Jul 2019 18:38:32 GMT',
        'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
        'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform',
        'content-length': '1383',
        vary: 'Origin, X-Origin' } },
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=user&fields=*&pageSize=1&q=name%20contains%20\'Kuppla%20Backup\'%20and%20trashed%20=%20false',
  _bodyInit: 
   { _data: 
      { size: 3415,
        offset: 0,
        blobId: '14B4C252-F8B4-49EA-A360-36C26D21BA64',
        type: 'application/json',
        name: 'files' } },
  _bodyBlob: 
   { _data: 
      { size: 3415,
        offset: 0,
        blobId: '14B4C252-F8B4-49EA-A360-36C26D21BA64',
        type: 'application/json',
        name: 'files' } } }
```

I used the example in google [File: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), and it works perfectly. From the response on this example page, I copied one file ID and tested the Download request from the mobile app and it worked as expected. The upload is also working fine.

The strange thing about this is that the File List request is not working as expected but the download/upload are working just fine. So there are no permission/authorization issues.

From the File List response above, does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: "File List API response changed" - what was it before and what is it now? Show the diffs.

Comment: @pinoyyid before the response was something like the example if the [File: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) google documentation link I provided above. The current response is in the question itself.